# Value stored to cell during its initialization is never read in cellForRowAtIndex method?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management, memory-leaks, uitableview

In my application in tableview cell for row at index method I use the following lines of code 
When my application is for analyze I got the following leak

code:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    //if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    //}

    // Configure the cell...
}
```

I got error like this:

> **Value stored to cell during its initialization is never read**

Comment: You do `cell =` twice, so of course the first assignation is lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You initialize the local variable called 'cell' in this line:

`UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];`

and then you immediately overwrite that value in the next line:

`cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];`

The analyzer is calling your attention to this.

In this particular case, this won't actually result in a leak. But it does mean you are not reusing cells, and so this will affect the performance of your table view.

Comment: Thanks for response i tried this one commented first line it doesnot give error.

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid recycling cells?

Comment: //if (cell == nil)  are you telling abt this line of code i have large no of rows  if i use this the data will be mixed i mean overwritten

Comment: Ok, what do you mean by "first line", and are you saying you are no longer getting the analyzer result? Is what you wanted? I would fix the bug that is causing your cells to be overwritten incorrectly. Cell reuse is important, you don't want to sacrifice that just to avoid fixing a bug in your cell reuse.

Answer (score 2):

You initialize the local variable called 'cell' in this line:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

and then you immediately overwrite that value in the next line:

```
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

The analyzer is calling your attention to this.

In this particular case, this won't actually result in a leak. But it does mean you are not reusing cells, and so this will affect the performance of your table view.

If you want to remove this warning & not worry about UITableView performance.then you need to add 2 lines code in your above code. Please follow bellow code.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell!=nil)
    cell=nil;
cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
```

Above code will work perfectly & remove the warning.